# Harry Potter not defending himself?

Tags: harry-potter

Before I ask this question on this SE, I looked on  the se if someone asked this question. As I'm asking myself why in the world doesn't Harry defend himself. For instance when the elf Dobby whirled the dessert on the guests. The Harry gets a letter that he did magic while he is underage. No where is it mentioned that Harry said I didn't do it it was the elf. What is this, is it his personality he can't defend himself or is this something else.

Comment: Defend himself to whom? The Ministry, or the Dursleys?

Comment: I'm sure this is answered somewhere in the CoS book, but I don't have it to hand atm.

Comment: @Mike.C.Ford yes, but this trait he has all over the books, between his friends, with the Dursley's, and grown ups around him.

Comment: @randal'thor what is CoS? I never heard of it.

Comment: @Nachmen CoS is Chamber of Secrets. but this incident is only mentioned once more and that is in OotP (Order of the Phoenix) in harry's hearing. fudge also mentioned that nobody complained after harry got the warning. after that the topic was dropped as far as i remember...

Comment: My question is why? Not particularly this incident, this trait is in all books?

Comment: @Nachmen CoS = *(Harry Potter and the) Chamber of Secrets*. Since Harry's signature spell is a defensive one (Expelliarmus), I don't think not being able/willing to defend himself is part of his personality.

Comment: Your making my query even better why?

Comment: I've given an answer, if necessary I can include many more quotations showing Harry standing up for himself. I'm not really sure how you came to the conclusion he doesn't - have you any other examples when this occurs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## **He does defend himself. This is one of his defining characteristics as a Griffindor.**

First of all, let's look at some occasions where Harry defends himself against false accusations, before moving on to your specific complaint (Dobby and the dessert). I was initially going to quote a few incidents from each book, but it turns out there are a LOT of them. Instead, I'll show a few that should highlight the point.

**Book 1 - Harry stands up to the Dursleys, protesting his innocence about climbing the school building (funnily enough, this was one of his first unwitting uses of magic).**

> On the other hand, he'd gotten into terrible trouble for being found
> on the roof of the school kitchens. Dudley's gang had been chasing him
> as usual when, as much to Harry's surprise as anyone else's, there he
> was sitting on the chimney. The Dursleys had received a very angry
> letter from Harry's headmistress telling them Harry had been climbing
> school buildings. But all he'd tried to do (**as he shouted at Uncle
> Vernon through the locked door of his cupboard**) was jump behind the
> big trash cans outside the kitchen doors.

**Book 2 - Harry stands up for himself repeatedly.**

First of all, Harry **does** insist he's innocent about the dessert.

> "What's been going on?" said Ron. "Why haven't you been answering my
> letters? I've asked you to stay about twelve times, and then Dad came
> home and said you'd got an official warning for using magic in front
> of Muggles -"
>
> "**It wasn't me** - and how did he know?"

When Harry is found beside Filches petrified cat...

> **"I never touched Mrs. Norris!" Harry said loudly**, uncomfortably aware
> of everyone looking at him, including all the Lockharts on the walls.

Harry later confronts the Hufflepuffs who are discussing the incident at the dueling club.

> "What do you want with him?" said Ernie in a quavering voice. "I
> **wanted to tell him what really happened with that snake at the Dueling
> Club**," said Harry.
>
> Ernie bit his white lips and then, taking a deep
> breath, said, "We were all there. We saw what happened."
>
> **"Then you
> noticed that after I spoke to it, the snake backed off?"** said Harry.
>
> "All I saw," said Ernie stubbornly, though he was trembling as he
> spoke, "was you speaking Parseltongue and chasing the snake toward
> Justin. "
>
> **"I didn't chase it at him!" Harry said, his voice shaking
> with anger.** "It didn't even touch him!"

Shortly after, when Harry is found with with the Petrified Justin and Nick...

> This left Harry and Professor McGonagall alone together. "This way,
> Potter," she said.
>
> **"Professor," said Harry at once, "I swear I didn't
> -"**

Mere minutes later he is found in Dumbledore's office with the smouldering remains of Fawkes.

> "Professor," Harry gasped. **"Your bird - I couldn't do anything - he
> just caught fire -"**

**Book 5 - Harry does in fact assert to the Minister of Magic that he didn't perform the Hover charm in book 2.**

> "Serious miscarriage, my hat!" said Fudge at the top of his voice.
> "Have you ever bothered to tot up the number of cock-and-bull stories
> this boy has come out with, Dumbledore, while trying to cover up his
> flagrant misuse of magic out of school? I suppose you’ve forgotten the
> Hover Charm he used three years ago -"
>
> **"That wasn’t me, it was a
> house-elf!"** said Harry.
>
> "YOU SEE" roared Fudge, gesturing flamboyantly
> in Harry’s direction. "A house-elf! In a Muggle house! I ask you."

### The Dessert Incident

Now, as to the dessert incident - what exactly would a 12 year old do? Write a strongly worded letter the government he barely knows about? He has no experience with magical law, no-one to ask about it, no procedures to follow. On top of that, he barely knows what a house elf is, and has been given a whole other mystery to solve regarding Dobbies odd clues.

**Given that he's a young child, suspects he wouldn't be believed, has no experience with the magical government, no context for the seriousness of the crime, AND that the letter was a warning with no apparent lasting consequences, it makes sense that Harry would drop it. These are all exceptional circumstances though - his normal attitude would be to immediately protest his innocence.**

Comment: This well structured well written with the facts on the table. I don't know why I had this view that he's not defending himself.

Answer (score 5):

Because whenever he tries, nobody believes him.

Throughout the first book, we see examples of the Dursleys mistreating him, and blaming him for everything that goes wrong. Perhaps some of these *are* actually his fault, as he is a wizard and it may have been magic manifesting itself, but Harry had no idea he was doing it. He was still blamed though.

He is blamed in the first few chapters for freeing the snake at the zoo, and also for the letters that keep showing up. These are both things that, from his point of view, he had nothing to do with and didn't have any control over.

How are you supposed to defend yourself from that? It seems entirely unreasonable to blame him for those occurrences (which it is, but the Dursleys are not particularly reasonable people), so how is he supposed to prove that he is not to blame? There is nothing he can do or say to make anyone listen to him.

Considering there are already 2 occurrences of this within the first few chapters of the first book, we can safely assume that it has been happening for his entire life. After a time you would just quit trying to defend yourself, as it is utterly futile.

Even when he discovers that he is a wizard and goes to Hogwarts, a place where he finally fits in and is actually respected, he is still ignored and his opinions dismissed. When he confronts Professor McGonagall about Snape being after the Philosopher's Stone, she immediately dismisses his accusations without hearing him out. Ultimately he *was* wrong, but that doesn't change the fact he wasn't listened to.

She does it also when he is caught out of bed and given detention, he is not allowed to explain his side of things. And she is one of the people he likes and trusts the *most*.

There is no one (adults anyway) who will listen to what he has to say, or his opinions, without immediately dismissing them. By the time the events with Dobby occur, why would he think anyone would believe him? Before this point he has never even met an elf, so considering that he has no evidence it seems like a pretty outrageous story considering he has had better explanations for other things, which were still not believed.

Comment: I understand the gist but the ministry didn't have to send in the first place. They for sure know about elves. If they new that magic was done they need to know that he didn't do it. The ministry is the force upholding law and order, and truth is part of that as a boy he wouldn't  be so broad minded that they are also corrupted.

Comment: I don't think it's so much thinking that they are corrupted as thinking that there's no one who believes him for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

He is habituated to people not believing him, and sometimes(in fact, many times) thrashed for speaking up, and he is just too happy narrowly escaping an expelling, and he is too happy to bring it up again.

1. If he tried to defend himself to the Dursleys, he'd rather get doubled up thrashing, as there is not one, but two more magical creatures in the house (Harry and Dobby), and the Dursleys just can't stand that.
2. He also doesn't know the rules of underage wizardry properly, being fresh out of the Muggle world. So, he is obviously afraid to speak up/defend himself before a huge ministry. Instead, he's happy being allowed to live in the magical world. (In case he was expelled for that, I am pretty positive he might have defended himself.)

Comment: I saw this already before but the truth is the truth. He didn't do it period.

Comment: @Nachmen No, my inference is that he is too satisfied to get away with a warning (and live a normal life in the magical world, which is more than what he ever wanted), and doesn't want to stir it up again. :)

Comment: He gets a thrashing? Are we talking literally? I know Dudley beat him up but does Vernon physically discipline Harry?

Comment: @MacCooper That was unknown. However, as it is mentioned multiple times that Vernon raised his fist threateningly at Harry, whenever he got angry at him.  So, it's a sensible inference to make IMO!

Comment: @Dawny33 oh, sure, I'm with you. Personally never made that inference myself; interesting how much darker it just got!

Comment: @MacCooper - there was also the almost casual swinging of frying pans at his head, from Petunia (CoS).  He dodges,but that suggests more than just threats, he knew *to* dodge.  There's also a fair bit of grabbing, shoving and dragging around from the adults, while Dudley's punches and blows are openly encouraged - and it's both implied and explicitly stated starvation and extended confinement were used as usual punishments.